# how to install playframework 2.6 in ubuntu?

Tags: playframework

hi im new to playframework but i have to install play framework so i download from [here](https://www.playframework.com/download)  but i have no idea how to setup it but i install java and other stuff 
if any one can you help me to setup playframework

> and my os is ubuntu

and my java version is 1.8.0 when i type `java -version` its show like that i follow some youtube tutorials also but its not solve my problem  any how i want to install playframework thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
1.Download jdk , java version 8, 
2.Set the jdk and jre bin folder path to system path variable, (in windows   restart)
3.Download SBT , install that.
4.Set the SBT bin folder path to system path variable.
5.download a playframework starter project ,
6.Go to the folder where build.sbt located and open terminal there,
7.Run the "sbt" command, at first it will take some times,
8.After completing the command run "compile" command,
9.After completing that run "run" command. 
:) The server will start in 9000 port. (http://localhost/9000)
Open browser, type http://localhost:9000
Your app running...........
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the instruction of the documentation:

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/Installing

Make sure `sbt` is installed. See [https://www.scala-sbt.org](https://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Setup.html)

Comment: i havge a one question with out sbt can install playframework? bcz im also plan to use but its for java

Comment: I never tried that - officially it uses SBT for Java as well. see https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/BuildOverview

Comment: You can download Palyframework template but after that you need to sbt for compile, test, and ...